# Sign-in error in Azure AD secured web application when suspending Multi-Factor Authentication

Tags: azure, owin, azure-active-directory, adal

We have implemented a multi-tenant single sign-on scenario in our ASP.NET web application using the OpenId Connect procotol with OWIN middleware. We have followed the official sample projects, such as:
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

By doing so, Office 365 users (or Azure AD users in general) can log in to our web application, which generally works fine.

Now, we have encountered an issue with the multi-factor authentication (MFA) feature of Azure AD Premium and the option "Don’t ask again for x days".
When logging in to our web application for the first time with MFA enabled and the "Don't ask" option, the authentication process succeeds. After closing and re-opening the browser, the log-in process does not work anymore.
Steps to reproduce in detail:

1. Ensure that the browser cache has been cleared.
2. Open browser and go to web application.
3. When being redirected to the Azure AD log-in page (login.microsoftonline.com), sign in with your Azure AD/O365 account credentials and check the option to store the sign-in information to be still authenticated after closing the browser.
4. Enter the MFA verification code which will be sent to your mobile device (or what else) and also check the option "Don’t ask again for x days".
5. You will be redirected to the web application as authenticated user.
6. Now close and re-open the browser.
7. Go to the web application again.
8. When being redirected to the Azure AD log-in page, you cannot proceed. Your account credentials have been stored, but you cannot continue. When clicking on the sign-in button again and again, nothing happens.

The following page says, the MFA feature is still in public preview, so maybe there is still a bug in the feature:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270518.aspx#user_suspend_mfa

We have already tried to use the WS-Federation middleware instead of OpenId Connect, but the issue still remains, so I do not think this is a protocol-related issue.

I am now trying to reach the responsible engineer team to report this bug. We would really appreciate to enable our users to sign in to our web app using MFA.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Dustin